# Call Carousel plugin issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

When I use on my web noConflict mode

```
 var $jq = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

I can use variable `jq` for normal jQuery functions, but I cant call owlCarousel plugin with this variable

```
$jq('document').ready(function(){
    $jq('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel(
  });
```

I have an error that .owlCarousel is not a function.

Is there a way how to call plugin with noConflict mode?

Answer (score 0):

`var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();` dont use true in [noConflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) for this plagin

```js
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
$jq('document').ready(function(){
    $jq('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    items:1,
    lazyLoad:true,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:3000,
    autoplayHoverPause:true,
   });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=1" data-src-retina="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=1-retina" alt="">
    <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=2" data-src-retina="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=2-retina" alt="">
    <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=3" alt="">
    <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=4" alt="">
    <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=5" alt="">
    <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=6" alt="">
    <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=7" alt="">
    <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=8" alt="">
    <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=9" alt="">
    <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=10" alt="">
    <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=11" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Try your other plugin. owl-carousel plugin can not support this code.

Comment: I tried to use Slick, but same thing happened. It doesnt work with true :(

Comment: A call order in your <head> section must be next:

**jQuery library №1;**
**noConflict for it;**
**jQuery library №2.**

Comment: see this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28403189/how-to-use-conflict-in-html-with-multiple-version-jquery

Comment: I did it exactly same way, but my "true" doesnt work and without it I get an error..

Comment: I just wonder what is difference between using .noConflict(); and .noConflict(true); ?